# Where should http headers be set?

Tags: http, model-view-controller

In a web application using an MVC layout, should HTTP Headers be set in the controller or the view? My thoughts:

- **Controller**: Setting the header here seems appropriate, as this is part of taking a request, and setting necessary variables to handle it on the server side.
- **View**: An HTTP header is really just a few lines of text above the rest of the content being served up, and that text is arguably the view.

I wouldn't gasp to see headers set in either location. What is the best practice?

Comment: controller seems right to me

Comment: @tm1rbrt any thoughts on the ambiguity I raised?

Comment: I see what you mean, but a view isn't necessarily what is shown on a screen. You could have a JSON view. As such, couldn't it be seen as more "whatever is presented?" And if so, isn't the header arguably part of what is presented?

Comment: View is responsible for producing response. HTTP headers are form of response. Where is the confusion?

Comment: Also, @tm1rbrt is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view’s responsibility is anything that is sent to the user. The format of the content doesn’t matter. The view doesn’t know how that content will be parsed – in a web browser, a console, Lynx …

An example: you want to debug your AJAX requests and send data about the inner processes to the browser. You don’t want to mangle that information into your DOM, so you use HTTP headers instead. These headers are meant to be **viewed** in the browser’s debugger. The view in your application just doesn’t know if you are actually looking at its output.

Basic rule: whenever you sent a single Byte to the user, use the view.